# difference between installation testing and compatibility testing?

Tags: testing, installation, compatibility

What is the difference between **Installation Testing** and **Compatibility Testing** in context of software Testing ?

Comment: Can you provide any further context?

Comment: hi tbsalling, Thanks for the reply, i need to know the exact difference between them .. since both the testing is like testing the environment of the application .. i'ma little bit confused can you explain it briefly .. Thank you

Comment: Yes - but you must know these words out of some sort of context? Is it a book you have read? Or where did you meet the terms "intallation testing" and "compatibility testing"? I could easily come up with some bla bla about it - but I have a feeling that in your case these terms mean something specific. So please add more input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminology in test is not something that is engraved somewhere and identical for everyone.
Nevertheless, my understanding would be:

- installation testing : testing the download, deploy and set-up and the Software. Test with different initial configurations (soft never installed before, soft installed and removed, soft here and we want to upgrade etc.).
- compatibility testing: testing the global behavior of your product (not just the install, but you would have to include it) on different platforms. Depending on your product and you are supposed to support, you will make variation on hardware, OS, browsers, databases etc.